# PHP: add variables into json_decode

Tags: php, json, string, paypal, concatenation

I want to add variables into a string in php. I googled and found the method of : "{$a}". However this doesn't work for me. I echoed it and it has literally echoed "{$a}" instead of the actual value of the variable. Here is my code:

```
$body= json_decode(
                            '{
                                "sender_batch_header":
                                {
                                  "email_subject": "SDK payouts test txn"
                                },
                                "items": [
                                {
                                  "recipient_type": "EMAIL",
                                  "receiver": "{$email}",
                                  "note": "Your 1$ payout",
                                  "sender_item_id": "Test_txn_12",
                                  "amount":
                                  {
                                    "currency": "CHF",
                                    "value": "{$actualAmount}" 
                                  }
                                }]
                              }',             
                            true);
```

And here is the echo of $body:

> { "sender_batch_header": { "email_subject": "SDK payouts test txn" },
> "items": [ { "recipient_type": "EMAIL", "receiver": "{$email}",
> "note": "Your 1$ payout", "sender_item_id": "Test_txn_12", "amount": {
> "currency": "CHF", "value": "{$actualAmount}" } }] }

The variables I am talking about are $email and $actualAmount. I debugged it and they both have a value it just does not get added to the string. Can anyone help?

Comment: The outer string is surrounded by single quotes, which means no matter what quotes you have on the inside, variables will not be parsed. Why are you building a json string and decoding it when you can just create an array or object yourself?

Comment: @aynber thanks a lot! you are right. Probably in the futurne i should create my own object but as I am pretty new to php this approach was a little bit clearer to me. Orhan had the right solution for me in this case! Thank you though!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A string literal can be different ways:

- [single-quoted](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.single)
- [double quoted](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.double)

You can use braces in double-quoted strings like: `"Hello {$foo}"` unfortunately your string variable is single-quoted. So we can use the concatenation operator ('.'), which returns the concatenation of its right and left arguments.

So let's try with concatenation operator;

```
 $body= json_decode(
                                '{
                                    "sender_batch_header":
                                    {
                                      "email_subject": "SDK payouts test txn"
                                    },
                                    "items": [
                                    {
                                      "recipient_type": "EMAIL",
                                      "receiver": "'.$email.'",
                                      "note": "Your 1$ payout",
                                      "sender_item_id": "Test_txn_12",
                                      "amount":
                                      {
                                        "currency": "CHF",
                                        "value": "'.$actualAmount.'" 
                                      }
                                    }]
                                  }',             
                                true);
```